# Java printing output of text file and checking first character

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, string-parsing

I think the commented out section of my code works. My issue is when I print out the string "s" I only get the last line of my text file.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class mainCode {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
      { 
          // We need to provide file path as the parameter: 
          // double backquote is to avoid compiler interpret words 
          // like \test as \t (ie. as a escape sequence) 
          File file = new File("F:\\Java Workspaces\\Workspace\\Files\\file.txt"); 

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
            String s = new String("");

            while (sc.hasNextLine())
                s = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(s);
//                if (s.substring(0,1).equals("p") || s.substring(0,1).equals("a") ){
//                    System.out.println(s);
//                }
//                else{
//                    System.out.println("Error File Format Incorrect");
//                }
      }
}
```

The output is just "a192" the lines before are "a191" and "a190"

Comment: Have you tried printing out the result of `.substring(0,10)`?  It might show you something is off in your file you're not expecting. (Just because the line prints with an "a" doesn't mean that's actually the first character.  Invisible characters exist.)

Comment: @markspace the output of the code only prints the last line even without the stuff I have commented out the only lines within the while loop are s=sc.nextLine(); and System.out.println(s); I also implemented a similar code in c++ without any problem. Also printing without using the variable "s" and just putting System.out.println(sc.nextLine()); prints every line properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation makes it look like your `while` executes multiple statements, but it doesn't.  Use braces to enclose statements you want to execute as a block.

```
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
            s = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);  // proper indentation
```

Probably what you want:

```
  while( sc.hasNextLine() ) {
     s = sc.nextLine();
     System.out.println( s );
  }
```

(I had to drop this into my IDE to find it.  My IDE labeled that second line as "Confusing Indentation" for me.  Good IDEs do that.)

Comment: Holy you are right I don't know how I did not notice that! Thank you!